# Фильтр массива обьектов по условия

Tags: javascript

Как отфильтровать такой массив и вывести только значения num
Тоесть пушать в новый массив значения num

Мой массив обьектов

```
[
            {
                "type": "seat",
                "vector": 1,
                "num": 3,
                "status": "booked"
            },
            {
                "type": "seat",
                "vector": 1,
                "num": 4,
                "status": "free"
            }]
```

Результат фильтра [3,4]

Comment: `arr.filter(filter_func).map((x) => x.num)`

Comment: @nörbörnën фильтр какой-то прилип ненужный

Comment: filter_func ??? напишите полностью пожалуйста для рабочего примера

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev в вопросе: `Как отфильтровать такой массив`

Comment: Результат фильтра [3,4] такой результат хочеться выдеть

Comment: ааа, думаю тут автор не так выразился: тк условий фильтрования то и не написал. я думаю ему просто мапнуть нужно  `const numbers = arr.map(({ num }) => num);`

Comment: Artem Gorlachev Cпасибо, немного не понял {num} этот стиль

Comment: это сахар, просто берем от объекта только нужное поле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать так (`{ num }` - это [деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring)):

```js
const items = [{
  "type": "seat",
  "vector": 1,
  "num": 3,
  "status": "booked"
},
{
  "type": "seat",
  "vector": 1,
  "num": 4,
  "status": "free"
}];

const onlyNums = items.map(({ num }) => num);
```